# boto3 dynamodb IN condition

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am reading official docs http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/conditions.html

You can create a condition like this:

```
Attr(key).eq(value)
```

Where you check if `value` equals to `key`'s value using `class Attr()` with eq method.

But how do you use a SQL IN operator?

I would like to query if value IN key's value

At the docs it just appear an In class and I dont see any example or how to use it

```
class In(ComparisonCondition):
    expression_operator = 'IN'
    has_grouped_values = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator `IN` cannot be used in `KeyConditionExpression` i.e. to get multiple hash key values using Query API. DynamoDB doesn't support this feature at the moment.

If you need to retrieve multiple hash key values, please use `Batch Get Item` api.

**Sample code:-**

```
email1 = "abc@gmail.com"
email2 = "bcd@gmail.com"

try:
    response = dynamodb.batch_get_item(
    RequestItems={
        'users': {
            'Keys': [
                {
                    'email': email1
                },
                {
                    'email': email2
                },
            ],            
            'ConsistentRead': True            
        }
    },
    ReturnConsumedCapacity='TOTAL'
)
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    item = response['Responses']
    print("BatchGetItem succeeded:")
    print(json.dumps(item, indent=4, cls=DecimalEncoder))
```

Comment: Why is `in` included for `boto3.dynamodb.conditions` but DynamoDB does not support it yet?

Comment: It seems to me, from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html, that the "in" operator is support, and should be supported for example in a Scan (in its FilterExpression, **not** KeyConditions). If not, why not?

Comment: @notionquest is saying "Operator IN cannot be used in KeyConditionExpression" - not that it can't be used at all. Dynamo can't use it to find items, however, it can be used to filter items. So, if you wanted, you could use it in FilterExpression or other forms of filtering.