# Boto3 is_in not working in scan operation

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm trying to do a scan for key values in a table, it works fine on query, but not on scan.  Am I missing something?

```py
def get_items_from_id_list(id_list, table_name, key_name):
  #setup resource
  table = get_dynamo_table(table_name, dynamodb_region_name)

  # scan
  condition_expression = Attr(key_name).is_in(id_list)
  result = table.scan(FilterExpression=condition_expression)

  # query for 1
  query_expression = Key(key_name).eq(id_list[0])
  result2 = table.query(KeyConditionExpression=query_expression)

  # !! result contains 0 items
  # !! result2 contains 1 item

  if not result.get('Count'):
    return []
  out = result['Items']
  del out['aws:rep:updatetime']
  return out
```

Comment: This was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829144/boto3-dynamodb-in-condition and it suggested that IN operators are not supported by DynamoDB's Scan, although to be honest, I didn't understand why.